# Блокировка кнопки

Tags: android, button, android-button

У меня есть проблемка, хочу сделать кнопку которая будет заблокирована пока не будет выполнено условие. А конкретнее хочу чтобы кнопка была серой, пока не будет полностью введен номер, потому кнопка поменяла бы цвет на синий и можно было бы сделать переход на новую активность. Т.е. в кратце ,когда номер полностью введен ,кнопка меняет цвет с серого на синий и разблокируется.

Comment: В свойствах кнопки установи Enabled = false, когда надо активировать установи setEnabled(true)

Comment: Все очень просто. Кнопке делаете setEnabled(false) (или в разметке устанавливаете это значение), Делаете валидатор ввода через addTextChangedListener() для EditText, при прохождении валидации ввода делаете кнопке setEnabled(true)

Comment: а можете написать пример кода, просто я только начинаю программировать и я не до конца понял

Answer (score 0):

```
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
            btn.setEnabled(s.length() == 8);
        }
    });
```

Comment: findViewById() кнопки крайне рекомендуется вынести за пределы слушателя (самое место рядом с инициализацией EditText). Так у вас при наборе каждого символа на клавиатуре заново будет искаться эта несчастная кнопка. Это довольно ресурсозатратная операция и именно благодаря таким решениям андроид имеет репутацию тормознутой и лагучей системы

Comment: Так же, до того, как какой либо символ на клавиатуре будет нажат, кнопка будет активна. Потом, при наборе каждого символа ее будет совершенно бессмысленно "долбить" отключением, хотя она и так отключена. Оптимизацию это тоже никак не улучшает. Какая то индусская школа программирования у вас тут во всей красе

Comment: у меня получается так что кнопка заблокирована всегда